# How to make "CTRL + ALT + T" open new Terminal window when one is already open?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and would like to know if there is some way to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new Terminal window even if one is already open (that is rather than just bring the currently open one to the front)?

Comment: In my installation CTRL+ALT+T always opens a new terminal regardless (GNOME 3.16.4).

Comment: In every gnome install I've just added "gnome-terminal" as a custom shortcut, and it's worked exactly as I expected it to, it opens a new terminal window. Is there some functionality you want that I'm missing?

Comment: @Mischka: No, I think that for some reason it doesn't work quite right on my version... But the current accepted answer seems to fix that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The funny thing is that on Unity, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> *does* open a new window, apparantly not on Gnome...

To make the setup:

1. First disable the existing command/key combination with the command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal ""
   ```

   Which will make <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> "available" again for another command.
2. Now open keyboard settings: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=<profilename>
   ```

   to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, where `<profilename>` is the name of your profile, most likely `Default`

From man `gnome-terminal`:

```
   --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
             Open  a new window containing a tab with the given profile.
             More than one of these options can be provided.
```

Comment: The answer is good, but also with `'<Primary><Alt>t'` for `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal` GNOME opens a new terminal per default.

Comment: @A.B. Good to know, apparently on OP's system it didn't for some reason...

Comment: Yes, that's strange.

Comment: @A.B. Indeed. I'm on GNOME and Ctrl+Alt+T opens a new terminal no matter if I have one opened already.

Answer (score 13):

It's pretty easy to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> alive in gnome:

1. Search for Keyboard shortcuts in Gnome home menu
2. Add a custom shortcut in Keyboard
3. Add (+)

   - Name: gnome-terminal
   - Command: `gnome-terminal`
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image: Adding custom commands]

Comment: easy and quick. Can be easily changed later. Good one.